# java.lang.ClassCastException when using custom classloader

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

I need to dynamically load a java class at runtime. For this purpose I'm using https://github.com/trung/InMemoryJavaCompiler.

The class that I need to load implements an interface that already is part of my application (this interface is therefore loaded by system-classloader). After the class is loaded, I cast it to the interface.

**UPDATE**: Sorry, but I was wrong about docker. That has of course nothing to do with docker, but with the fact that I'm starting the application via command line: `java -jar ...`. When the application is started from intellij it works. When it's started via command line java.lang.ClassCastException is thrown when I try to cast.

The class loader of the real interface is org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClass Loader@2a84aee7 while the class loader of the dynamically loaded interface is sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302. Thank you for helping me identifying the problem.

What could I do to ensure that the same class loader is used?

Would it be a good idea to always make the custom class loader child of the interface's class loader: `new DynamicClassLoader(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader())`?

Comment: Check if `generatedInstance.getClass().getInterfaces()` contains YourInterface and that class loader of these interfaces is equal to `YourInterface.class.getClassLoader()`.

Comment: @apangin is right. check whether the class and interface are loaded by the same classloader first. :)

Comment: Docker shouldn't change how the JVM loads classes.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I updated the question. The classloader of the real interface is `org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClass
Loader@2a84aee7` while the class loader of the dynamically loaded interface is `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302`. Thank you for helping me identifying the problem. What could I ensure that the same class loader is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `DynamicClassLoader` needs to delegate to the ClassLoader that loads `MyInterface`.

`new DynamicClassLoader(MyInterface.class.getClassLoader())` should be fine.

Comment: Hi @apangin, can you pls have a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197687/how-does-java-classloader-identifies-duplicate-classes