# How does java classloader identifies duplicate classes?

Tags: java, jvm, dynamic-class-loaders

Let us say I have a java project where I have added 2 different jars in my classpath. Java classloader found some duplicate classes in the 2 jar and then only one among them will be loaded.

How does classloader decide that 2 classes in the classpath are same ? Just by class Name or packageName.className Or it compares each byte code of those classes ?

Comment: There is no  class name without any package name in view of the class loader. It always load a class with package name, So not String is loaded, it is java.lang.String loaded

Comment: @Jens yes but if 2 different classes have same fully qualified name but different code, will classloader treat them as duplicate ?

Comment: A classpath works exactly the same as an execution path in any operating system:  search the path’s entries in order, and the first one with a match wins.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin a clas will only refernced by this name, No code analyses

Comment: @Jens , then why below answer is downvoted ?

Answer (score 0):

It decides just by fully-qualified name (package + class name), and it loads (in general - depends on classloader), the first class found on the classpath. There is no bytecode comparision.